# Need help in determing what, if any, tools can be used to create a free Flash game

Tags: flash, tools, actionscript

Yes I proudly -and sadly- declare that I am a complete nincompoop when it comes to Flash, and I have been fishing around the big wide web for information. The reason for this is that I have been contracted to create a game(s) for a website -the usual flash-based games caveat. Please I do not mean things like by those gaming generator websites, I mean small yet professional games- but the caveat, as always, is that impossible dream: it needs to be done all for free. The budget...well imagine it as not there.

Annoyingly is that I am a game designer yes, but with a ridiculously tight deadline I haven't got much time to re-learn (ah the heady days of programming at uni) everything by the end of March, so I'd like to ask some people who know their stuff rather than keep looking at a gazillion different things.

This is my understanding: with the flash sdk you can create a game, albeit you need to be pretty programming savvy. FlashDevelop helps there -yet I am not entirely sure how. Yet even FD says to use Flash for the animation/graphics.

Yes its undeniably powerful but as I said there is the unattainable demand of no money. The million dollar question: what, if any, tools can I use to create a free flash game?

Answer (score 3):

This [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/325/how-can-i-develop-flash-games-without-expensive-software) pretty much covers the software part.

Then I suggest you use a framework like [Flixel](http://flixel.org/) or [Flashpunk](http://flashpunk.net/) for your game as it will allow you to:

1. Build a game rather quickly and...
2. Doesn't require Flash IDE to create graphics, since these engines are Bitmap based (so you could use GIMP or other image editing software to create your sprites).

Comment: Thanks Bummzack: got another mention of Flixel when posed same question on another forum, so methinks I will explore that area.

Answer (score 1):

i have been there. we knocked out a simple flash platform ages ago as2 back in the day. i would recommend the same engine but they never updated to as3 :( but it did save a lot of time.

so in short find a few game engines i listed to below take a quick look at the tutorials of each and then glance their api's. once you have found one you like batter down the hatch get the coffee brewing and go for it.

http://pushbuttonengine.com/

flixel(dot)org   (i am only allowed to post two links cause i am noob)

both those engines are free.

next comes creative. I would hope they at least sources you the assets are got you a designer if. Maybe you can do it your self. if not you can get assts from the link bellow double check the licence for each though its always tricky when making a commercially funded game  :)  prroz the internet you can get some cheap game assts too that are quite nice and with a few little amends they can become quite uniques if you dont mind a little pixel pushing :)

http://funplosion.com/free-assets.html

as for for the development environment using the flash IDE will make bundling up the assets easier but it is not essential. the engine would normally handel most of the animations and you can bundel the assets using the free flex compiler it would just take a little more time.

personally if i had any money at all after buying assets i would spend it on flash then if there was any money left after that FLash Builder and if by some miracle i had any money left i would get the FLash Builder plugin Source Mate. If you are unsure about any of these applications you could try them you can normally get 30day free trials to give them a whirl before you buy

well good luck :)

Comment: Cheers abe: lol no, there aint no assets, no nuttin: but hey opportunities are few and far between, so I go for it. We do have an artist though, and they want to follow his style, so hand drawing then converting into Flash-ish it will be! Thanks again!

Comment: no worries buddy  :)